# Is it OK to say thanks to an editor in a comment for correcting my spelling?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

I always try my best, but my English is somehow very bad. I'm used to thanking people in comments for editing my post with grammatically correct English.

But is this making unnecessary noise to my post or is it OK?

Comment: You may wish to have a look at [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment)

Comment: Im pretty sure You can't  Upvote an edit. so ?

Comment: @JonClements If only we could target MSE for duplicate closure :)

Comment: _"You can't Upvote an edit. so ?"_ No. But the editor will automatically gain 2 points of reputation if the edit was accepted and they have less than 2k rep.

Comment: If only an humble thank was not concidered as a waste of space. It's not about beeing polite or rewarding low rep user. It's more like a real natural thank you. And showing that you care at least a little bit about your post.

Comment: @PierreLebon As far as I am concerned not hearing back from the user means they liked my edit.  I do not need an explicit thank you.  I'm just trying to make the site better and a side effect of that is making other people content better.

Comment: Comments are, by design, transient and ephemeral (*lasting only a short time; existing briefly; temporary* and *lasting a very short time; short-lived*). So someone may flag your comment as "obsolete" and it may get deleted after a while. In the mean time, your sincere thanks were already transmitted to the intended receiver :)

Comment: @RadLexus, Well so thats a win-win. I stay human. And Thanks-hunter can punch me via flag system. Because They really act like they wee offended by a thanks, exept if they are the intended reciever ( some one just teached me this word).

Comment: An expression of gratitude is usually appreciated if someone has done you a favor. It is not expected for edits improving a post's language, but shouldn't offend anyone. It might get deleted later on, but so are many comments with much more valuable content.

Answer (score 8):

No, I don't think it's a good idea to thank the editor in a comment. Such comments don't contain any useful content, and for other members of community are just noise. If I saw such a comment, I'd flag it as "not constructive" or "too chatty".

For more information, see [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180/310998) on Meta Stack Exchange.